# Update single field in MongoDB in a single embedded document

Tags: ruby, mongodb

We have some embedded documents that look like this:

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("4e402353bc9f6ec5a6000001"),
"first_name" : "Chris",
"last_name" : "Jones",

    "alerts" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4f7cd6ffc067db00070022d4"),
        "name" : "Default",
        "email_frequency" : "weekly",
        "interested_industries" : [
            "Computer Software",
            "Internet"
        ],
        "interested_employers" : [
            "Facebook",
            "AOL"
        ],
        "interested_skills" : [ ],
        "matches" : [
            ObjectId("4ee46a2a0dd0c70017000365"),
            ObjectId("4efa1707bacfa40001012b65"),
            ObjectId("4e402376bc9f6ec5a6000a7a"),
            ObjectId("4e4e0eb8d052fc4028021f66"),
            ObjectId("4ee55d8500ca410014000003"),
            ObjectId("4ee63d06d96b850001008688"),
            ObjectId("4e57be7ed052fc606a002335"),
            ObjectId("4f05d47d9ce340001702ba42"),
            ObjectId("4f200ffcaf5f34000e0021a4"),
            ObjectId("4e4de701d052fc33da00052f")
        ],
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2012-05-03T18:26:14.774Z")
    }
]
 }
```

Since the document above is contained in an array, I'm having trouble picking it out form the selector with something like this:

```
User.collection.update({"_id" => user.id}, {:$set => {"alert.matches" => matches}})
```

But this will update all #alerts matches. I just want to update the one alert with the ID "4fa7fd60e5be08bcc9000644".

Comment: It's better to post exact json document.

Comment: This is about the ruby driver implementation, JSON isn't relevant.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what is it that I see here. If people can't help you, it becomes relevant :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably use the [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) to identify the array element:

> **The $ positional operator**
>
> The $ operator (by itself) means "position of the matched array item in the query". Use this to find an array member and then manipulate it.

So perhaps something like:

```
User.collection.update(
    { :_id => user.id, :matches => BSON::ObjectId('4e40238dbc9f6ec5a6000eed') },
    { :$set => { 'alert.matches.$' => matches } }
)
```

But as Sergio notes, it is difficult to tease out the structure of your documents based on the limited information in your question.

---

Looks like more information came in after I answered and it looks like:

```
{ :$set => { 'alerts.$.matches' => ... } }
```

is what you need. And you will need to include `:matches` in the query so that `$` has something to refer to.

Comment: Just added the structure of the document.

Comment: I found the following query did it:

User.collection.update({"alerts._id" => alert.id}, { :$set => { "alerts.$.matches" => ["WTF???"] }})

Comment: This assumes I have to have an index on "alerts._id" right? Also, does the positional operator depend on the selector?

IE. If my selector was {"_id" => user.id}, then the positional wouldn't work right?

Comment: @user577808: You don't need an index. If you don't include the array in the search then there wouldn't be anything for `$` to refer to. The documentation I linked to has a bit more information on the positional operator: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: Was there a stray 'enter' there? Looks like your comment got cut off.

Comment: yes, I decided to delete the comment and upvote the answer instead :)

Comment: Re: index, since you need to refer to the array in the selector, you'd certainly need an index for the query to be anywhere near performant I would imagine. We have over a million user documents all of which have several "alerts" in the embedded array. I'm not missing something am I?

Comment: @user577808: I think you'll need an index if you want it be practical but MongoDB will go ahead and try if you don't have an index. So technically you don't need an index but practically you do.