# Change field in object in array of object

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a field `achivment` with an array of objects. I need to update the field `currentPoints` in one object that I will find by field `name` in the array.

Code model of mongoose:

```
const achive = new Schema(
   {
      achiveId: ObjectId,
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      finishedPoints: { type: Number, required: true },
      currentPoints: {
         type: Number,
         default: 0,
         set: function (v) {
            if (v >= this.finishedPoints) this.isFinished = true;
            return v;
         }
      },
      isFinished: { type: Boolean, default: false }
   },
   { _id: false }
);

const achivesSchema = new Schema({
   userId: ObjectId,
   achivement: [achive]
});
```

Code query:

```
export async function progressAchive(req, res) {
   const value = 3;
   try {
      const test = await Achives.updateOne(
         {
            userId: req.user._id,
            achivement: { $elemMatch: { name: req.params.nameAchive } }
         },
         { $set: { achivement: { currentPoints: value } } },

         { new: true }
      );
      res.json(test);
   } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
   }
}
```

Instead of updating, it removes all objects from the array and leaves them one object with the `currentPoint` field. How can I update this like I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update single field in MongoDB in a single embedded document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506316/update-single-field-in-mongodb-in-a-single-embedded-document)

Comment: you could also try first reading all values and writing them back into the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following for update

```
    const test = await Achives.updateOne(
      {
        userId: req.user._id, 
      },
    {
      $set:{"achivement.$[el].currentPoints": value}
    }, 
    { 
      arrayFilters:[{
        "el.name": req.params.nameAchive
      }],
      new: true
    }
  );
```